# UnboundLocalError in the same function - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

This piece of code in python is outputting an error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'accelY' referenced before assignment ". But accelY has already been assigned in the same function. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    accelY = -2

        y += accelY
```

Comment: `But accelY has already been assigned in the same function.` No. It hasn't. It will only be assigned if you meet certain conditions. If you fail to meet those conditions, and reach the line that tries to use `accelY`, you'll see your error.

Comment: use `accelY = 0` before `for event` loop to set default value. And to clear it automatically in next loop so it will stop moving when you stop pressing `SPACE`

Answer (score 0):

`accelY` isn't *necessarily* set earlier in the function; if there is no `event` with the specified type & key, it won't be.

Answer (score 0):

At start before you press `SPACE` your code works like

```
while True:

    y += accelY
```

so it try to use `accelY` which doesn't exist yet.

It is good to set default value at start

```
accelY = 0

while True:

    # rest of code

    y += accelY
```

---

BTW: But there will be other problem. When you stop pressing `SPACE` then `accelY` will be still `2` so you should set value `0` with event `KEYUP`

```
accelY = 0

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                accelY = -2

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                accelY = 0

    y += accelY
```